# what is the pictured plumbing item and what is its purpose?

Tags: plumbing, heating, copper-pipe

I need to replace a short run of pipe in my basement.  The attached photo is of the return line in a baseboard hot water heating zone.  I do not know what the item in the photo is.

What is the pictured item?  Is it something that I need to replace, or can it be safely left out when I replace the run of pipe?

[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that looks like a balance valve.

It needs to be set to control the flow balance between sections in heating systems.

If you change / replace pipes then all the balance valves will need to be checked and set appropriately.

Comment: Aha - interesting.  This is indeed one of three return "legs" (don't know better term) that merge together just downstream of this balance valve.  The other "legs" each have a similar component, although different than this one, that looks like it may serve a similar purpose.  So some sort of flow balance would make sense.

Comment: I think the primary reason is as stated in this answer.  But also, if ALL your zones have valves on both the out and return legs, you may be able to isolate the boiler equipment (pump, fill valve, PRV, bladder, etc etc) from the system, and thereby be able to do maintenance or swap bad components without emptying the system.       Similarly, to isolate zones from one another and perform maintenance on one zone without emptying the others.